# Better Sorting on Site Search

Tags: bug, status-declined, android-app, search, top-bar

There are a few places where one can search for sites. Ones that I have found:

1. New Top Bar, *More Stack Exchange Communities* section
2. [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues)
3. Android App > Left Pull in Menu > All Sites

I have found that for #2 and #3 in this list, search results sorting does not act the way that it should (as it does for #1).

In the New Top Bar, it seems that the search results are sorted using this order:

1. Site name starts with your search string
2. Site name includes your search string
3. Site description includes your search string

For #2 and #3, it looks like it is matching all sites that contain the string within the title or description and then throw them out in some random order.

So searching for "sk" in the top bar gives results in this order:

1. Skeptics
2. Ask Different
3. Ask Patents
4. Ask Ubuntu
5. Database Administrators (has the word "skills" in the description)

Searching for "sk" on android app or SE Leagues gives:

1. Ask Ubuntu
2. Ask Different
3. Database Administrators
4. Skeptics
5. Ask Patents

Looks like it is just a random order.

I think that the top bar sort is much better - just more intuitive at guessing what I am trying to look for. Can this be standardized across all site searches?

Comment: I don't know about SE Leagues, but mobile apps are using [SE API](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?page=1&pagesize=9999&filter=!8IeYYZbP6mZHKWAuMLy-E) as their data source. Running the linked API and searching for "sk" gave the same order, so looks like they only filtered out the sites without doing any further manipulation (e.g. sorting). Reasonable bug report, btw.